# Mount EXT3 with 16KB blocks

Tags: linux, ext3

I have a failing Sparc based Netgear ReadyNAS that uses LVM on Raid with EXT3 partitions with a 16KB block size. I would like to pull the drives out of the NAS and mount them read only in a Linux box. The issue is that from what I have read x86 PCs cannot (could not) read 16 KB blocks. The suggestions I have seen are to use [fuse-ext2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-ext2/). The issue is that the information I can find on the web is a number of years old. What is the best way to mount an EXT3 partition with 16 KB blocks?